# How to assign delegate events to particular Dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I want to specify click event to particular textfield in my web page, it's id value is `service`.

Even If I pass another element using `setElement()` to view, still I want to apply that click event on text-field(id:service).

view code:

```
var addService=Backbone.View.extend({
    events:{
        "click #service":"alertfunction"
    },
    alertfunction:function(event){
        alert("working");
    }
});
var addFunctionObj=new addService({el:$("div")});
```

html code:

```
<div align="center" id="div2">
    <input type="text" id="service" style="width: 200px; height: 20px; color: white; background: green" placeHolder="Enter Service"/>
    <input type="text" id="price" style="width: 200px; height: 20px; color: white; background: green" placeHolder="Enter Price"/>
    <input type="button" id="add" align="center" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; color: white; background: green" value="AddService"/>
    <span>I am Normal Text</span>
</div>
```

testcases :

Initially If I click on text-field(service),getting alert even If you pass `div` to view.
But If I pass the following names to view using `setElement`,click event is not working on text-field(service).

```
view.setElement('#add')
view.setElement('input')
view.setElement('span')
```

again If you pass `div or #div2` to view, click event is working fine on text-field(service).But If you pass the above elements to view,it's not working. Why?

What I want : If you pass any element to view,click event should be work on text-field(service). Is it possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not how Backbone works.

What the following code does is listen for click events for children of the "this.el" that bubble up.

```
events:{
    "click #service": "alertfunction"
}
```

This means that you cannot set "this.el" to be input#add because this element has no children with the id #service.

**Works**

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" id="service" />
</div>

var addFunctionObj=new addService({el:$("div1")});
```

**Does not work**

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
<input type="text" id="service" />

var addFunctionObj=new addService({el:$("div1")});
```

The second examples does not work because #service is **not** a child of this.el. As long you "pass" it an element that does not have #service as a child element then it will never work.